# Cross domain error even when ajax called made from same domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am making an ajax call to check username availability. The url to call is hardcoded in the js file. e.g http://abc.com/users/check_availability.

Now when i make the ajax call from http://abc.com it works fine, however if i make the call from http://www.abc.com, it gives a cross domain error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.com/users/check_availability?username=sd. Origin http://www.abc.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

How do i resolve this ? Is jsonp the only way ?

Comment: Redirect any requests for pages on `www.abc.com` to `abc.com`. You can do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you're using Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting alternate HTTP header values when your service returns data:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:"Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token"
```

This worked for us when trying to make REST calls to services under different sub-domains.

You don't have to make Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * you can probably be more restrictive. But we tried this just to check if it will work.

Just to clarify - we still use json and not jsonp

Comment: Thanks Sharath, we added header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http:// www . abc.com") in http://abc.com/users/check_availability and it started working.